# Alterar value de um input hidden com jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Olá, eu gostaria de alterar o value do input hidden. O input Que quero mudar tem id = Tipo.
Quero mudar assim que eu clica no link Tipo 2, quero alterar seu value para 2. Como eu consigo fazer isso?

```html
 <script src="https:/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

 <label id="lb1">Nome: </label>
 <input type="text" id="ip1" placeholder="Digite seu Nome" required autofocus/>
 <br>
 <label id="lb2"> Sobrenome: </label>
 <input type="text" id="ip2" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome" required/>
      // <a href="javascript: fTipo1()">tipo 1</a>
 //<a href="javascript: fTipo2()">tipo 2</a>
 
 <input type="hidden" id="Tipo" value="1"/>
 <script>
  
  
  function fTipo1(){
   var Nome = $("#ip1").val();
   var Tipo = $("#Tipo").val();
   window.location.href="href.php?Nome="+Nome+"&Tipo="+Tipo;
  }
  function fTipo2(){
   
   $('#Tipo').change(function(){
       $('2 > #Tipo').val($(this).val());
       alert($("#Tipo").val());
   });
   
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As duas funções JavaScript que fez para mim não fizeram sentido e eu não consegui nem entender qual era o objetivo delas, então não poderei analisá-las. Você diz que deveria alterar o valor do campo, mas em uma função você faz um redirecionamento para outra rota e na outra você atribui um evento `change` no campo.

Para alterar o valor do campo basta atribuir o valor na propriedade `value` dele:

```js
const tipo = document.getElementById("tipo")

function setTipo(novoTipo) {
  tipo.value = novoTipo
  console.log("Tipo alterado para", tipo.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="tipo" value="1">

<button onClick="setTipo(1)">Tipo 1</button>
<button onClick="setTipo(2)">Tipo 2</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado galera!!!

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode colocar uma *listener* no `link Tipo 2` que quando clicado vai pegar o seu `input` `hidden` e colocar `tipo.value = 2;` mudando o value dele para 2... 
*Coloquei um `console.log` só para vc ver que mudou*

```js
let t2 = document.getElementById('t2');

function muda(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tipo = document.getElementById('Tipo');
    console.log(tipo);

//agora ele muda o value para 2 e tb faz o console.log confirmando pra vc ;)
    tipo.value = 2;
    console.log(tipo);
}

t2.addEventListener('click', muda)
```

```html
<a id="t2" href="#">tipo 2</a>

<input  type="hidden" id="Tipo" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um hash no `href` dos links, adicione uma classe (coloquei `class="tipo"`) em cada um e um dataset `data-tipo = "1"` no link de valor 1 e `data-tipo = "2"` no link de valor 2 e use um evento click na classe `.tipo` cancelando o efeito do click com `event.preventDefault()`.

Ao clicar num dos links, você pega o valor do dataset do link clicado e coloca no input hidden e um `if` para verificar se o valor é 1 ou 2 e faz o que quer de acordo com o valor.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei o input hidden como `text` e comentei a linha do `window.location.href` apenas para visualizar a mudança de valor:

```js
$(".tipo").click(function(event){

   event.preventDefault();
   
   var tipo = $(this).data("tipo"); // pega o valor do dataset
   $("#Tipo").val(tipo); // altera o input hidden
   
   if(tipo == 1){
      var Nome = $("#ip1").val();
      // window.location.href="href.php?Nome="+Nome+"&Tipo=1";
   }else if(tipo == 2){
      alert(2);
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lb1">Nome: </label>
 <input type="text" id="ip1" placeholder="Digite seu Nome" required autofocus/>
 <br>
 <label id="lb2"> Sobrenome: </label>
 <input type="text" id="ip2" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome" required/>
      // <a class="tipo" data-tipo="1" href="#">tipo 1</a>
 //<a class="tipo" data-tipo="2" href="#">tipo 2</a>
 
 <input type="text" id="Tipo" value="1"/>
```